# neo4j batch import cache type issue

Tags: neo4j

I am pretty new to neo4j and facing the following issue. When executing the batch-import (Micheal Hunger - batch importer) command I get this error about the cache_type settings. It is recommending gcr settings, but these are only available in the enterprise edition.

Help is very appreciated, thanks.

**System Info:**
win7 32bit 4G RAM (3G usable), jre7, neo4j-community-1.8.2

**Data: (very small test data)**
nodes.csv (tab-separated) 13 nodes
rels.csv (tab-separated) 16 relations

**Execution and Error:**

C:\Daten\Studium\LV HU Berlin\SS 2013\Datamanagement and BI\Neuer Ordner>java -server     -Xmx1G -jar target\batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar target\db nodes.csv rels.csv

Using Existing Configuration File

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad value 'none' for setting 'cache_type': must
     be one of [gcr]
        at org.neo4j.helpers.Settings$DefaultSetting.apply(Settings.java:788)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.Settings$DefaultSetting.apply(Settings.java:708)
        at        org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSetting$SettingWrapper.apply(GraphDatabaseSetting.ja    va:215)
        at     org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSetting$SettingWrapper.apply(GraphDatabaseSetting.ja    va:189)
        at        org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.ConfigurationValidator.validate(ConfigurationValidator.java:    50)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.applyChanges(Config.java:121)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.<init>(Config.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.<init>(Config.java:79)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.<init>(BatchInserterImpl.java:83)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.<init>(BatchInserterImpl.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:60)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.createBatchInserter(Importer.java:40)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.<init>(Importer.java:26)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:54)
```

**Batch.properties:**

```
dump_configuration=false

cache_type=none

use_memory_mapped_buffers=true
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=5M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=5M
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=200M
```

Comment: the batch importer has a dependency on enterprise, you can use it in testing/development, I think if you add that it should be good.

Comment: thank you for the quick responses, but can you be a little more specific. I am very new to the whole neo4j development and usage, so I need to know where to add something and what in more detail. Do you mean that I just can use the enterprise edition for testing/dev?

Answer (score 0):

ran into the same problem as you and i changed the line in batch.properties

`cache_type=none` to `cache_type=gcr` and it worked. not sure about how the speed changes for this. Not sure why the other options `none`, `soft`, `weak`, `strong` are not working. 
Maybe Michael can give an answer to this?

Got the answer from the neo4j documentations
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html#_object_cache